# How to remove certain elements from an array using a conditional test in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a program that goes through an array of ints and calculates stdev to identify outliers in the data. From here, I would like to create a new array with the identified outliers removed in order to recalculate the avg and stdev. Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: Two arrays, two indexes. Use the input index to go through each element of the input array. Copy an element to the output array if it passes the test, and then increment the output index.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty simple solution to the problem that involves switching your mindset in the `if` statement (which isn't actually in a for loop it seems... might want to fix that).

```
float dataMinusOutliers[n];
int indexTracker = 0;
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if (data[i] >= (-2*stdevfinal) && data[i] <= (2*stdevfinal)) {

        dataMinusOutliers[indexTracker] = data[i];
        indexTracker += 1;
    }
}
```

Note that this isn't particularly scalable and that the `dataMinusOutliers` array is going to potentially have quite a few unused indices. You can always use `indexTracker - 1` to note how large the array actually is though, and create yet another array into which you copy the important values in `dataMinusOutliers`. Is there likely a more elegant solution? Yes. Does this work given your requirements though? Yup.